# Noise generator

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, dac

I want this circuit to continuous generate signal at the output of the ADC with thermal noise. The signal of interesting is generated by the DAC, and noise is added to this signal. When there is no signal at DAC, only noise is sampled by the ADC. The amp op sum signal from the DAC and the noise from zener diode. As the op-amp is in an inverter configuration, values at the output of the ADC must be digitally corrected. Is this going to work as expected? Any positive comment is welcome.

[image]

Comment: With all respect, what is the exact purpose of this circuit? What is the input to the DAC? Is this a white noise generator?

Comment: Input is some signal like a sine wave, for example.

Comment: You want to add thermal noise to an input signal? Most desire the opposite...

Comment: Yes! This is what I want.

Comment: The op-amp is a voltage adder giving high gain to the noise generated by the zener diode. This noise is added to whatever signal I generate at the DAC.

Comment: One more question. How much additive noise?  You have no voltage for your diode. A ~30V diode will produce so much avalanche noise that it might totally swamp your input signal, so all you'll get as output is white noise.

Comment: Nice you pointed so much noise may be generated by the zener diode directly. Perhaps high gain is not needed! At the output of the op-amp the SNR must be about 6dB.

Comment: There is no consideration for DC bias, , wrong polarity CM input range, 1k gain is too high, Zener DC current will offset the output must be AC coupled, actually nothing useful here.

Answer (score 2):

Very unlikely you'll get any digital data from the ADC because the opamp will produce voltages below zero volts due to it being configured as an inverter and being fed signals above zero volts. Inverters make positive signals negative.

Also the DAC and ADC appear not to be powered so that's another nail in the coffin. Ditto the opamp.

Comment: To some point you are right but some adc allow the input range voltage to be configured. Besides that, the architecture is the point of my question.

Comment: No, not to some point at all. The circuit in your question is not good at all.

Comment: A note that this schematic is a sketch: far from being a concluded work. It is a primary design! Any positive comment is welcome.

Comment: So, you've added the word "positive" to your question. Let me be clear about this: expecting only positive comments DOES NOT mean you get a favourable push in the right direction. After all, I could say that the circuit has nice lines and is clearly presented BUT that wouldn't improve your chances of being able to design a circuit that works. Take it on the chin and either move on with the cristicism or eroneously convince yourself that this circuit will work (but don't try it out unless you are prepared for disappointment).

Comment: Dear Andy. I know the circuit is not complete; that is why I am here trying to understand what is missing. I accept criticism if it move somehow the design forward. Critics like "it will not work" only moves backward. I accept criticism, believe that! I will improve the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Simulation with LTspice says the circuit will work as expected. So I don't see any need for modification.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add information, high-pass filter after DAC has fc=7.2343MHz, then some square wave generated by the DAC will enter op-amp like the picture bellow.

[image]